# Gem mongo_mapper_ext (0.2.4) has an invalid gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gemfile, gemspecs

I'm trying to bundle my Rails app properly but when i add the mongo_mapper_ext gem to the Gemfile i always get an error like:

> Unfortunately, the gem mongo_mapper_ext (0.2.4) has an invalid
>   gemspec. As a result, Bundler cannot install this Gemfile. Please ask
>   the gem author to yank the bad version to fix this issue. For more
>   information, see http://bit.ly/syck-defaultkey.

Even when my Gemfile specifies a different version than 0.2.4

```
# database
gem 'mongo', "1.4.1"
gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'mongo_mapper_ext', "0.2.7"
```

Any idea about the origin of the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have more info about this:

If you are using bundler 1.1.x this could be the problem

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1715

And this the solution:

```
bundle install --full-index
```

It seems to be a problem between bundler 1.1.x and Rubygems indexes.